# Flutter retrieving an array from cloud firestore: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'string'

Tags: flutter, dart

I stored an array of urls in cloud_firestore but failed to display the pics from the retrieved DocumentSnapshot.
when i use pics : ds["pics"].toSring i get a list of pics only separated by commas, making it hard to point to a string in the list and yet i want to display these lists separately.

```
new Expanded(child: StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('dimandPosts').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: const Text('Loading events...'));
    }
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
        return new Lost_Card(pics : ds["pics"]);
      },
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    );
  },
))


 class Lost_Card extends StatelessWidget {

  //All the card variables
  final String cName, id, photoUrl, nickName, country, phoneNumber, address,
      cQuantity, cPrice, cLocation, cLead, cDescribe, sex, pics;
  final IconData icon;
  final Color iconBackgroundColor;
  final ShapeBorder shape;

  Lost_Card({

    this.icon,
    this.iconBackgroundColor,
    this.shape, this.cName, this.id, this.photoUrl, this.nickName, this.country, this.phoneNumber, this.address, this.cQuantity, this.cPrice, this.cLocation, this.cLead, this.cDescribe, this.sex, this.pics,

  });

  void pop() {
    print(cName);
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: Column(
            // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .height / 4,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .height / 2.5,

                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  pics),
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown),

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                          radius: 15.0,
                          child: Text(
                            cName ?? '',
                            textScaleFactor: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        height: 65.0,
                        width: 35.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                              Text(
                                "1P",
                                textScaleFactor: 0.5,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text(
                    cPrice ?? '',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Add To Cart",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    ),
                    onPressed: pop,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "\$5",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

[This is the link to my document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1q7p.png)

Comment: could you specified the issue? does it gave any errors? are the urls actually retrieving correctly? did you check if is a IP blocking issue? does it happen with every picture?

Comment: The whole snapshot is retrieved but the error comes when i try to display the urls in the array

Comment: your method `Lost_Card` probably excpect a String. So, use `ds["pics"].toString() `

Comment: Hi @enochmbuga, can you show us the structure of your documents?

Comment: @RubensMelo looks like he's sending the entire array to the grid and he should be sending only one index at the time.

enochmbuga could you post your Lost_Card Widget as well?

Comment: Thanks @RubensMelo ds["pics"].toString() solve the problem but gave rise to another. i now have a list [xxxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx] separated with commas and have no idea how to pic on any of the four becouse pics[n] only returns x

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla seems nothing is blocking because when i use `ds["pics"].toString()` i get the whole list however cant use it because its only separated by commas. Your idea of sending only one index at a time may work wonders for me thou i don't know how to execute it. thanks

Comment: This is what i retrieve **[https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/laserdimander.appspot.com/o/IGueNtIiYQWjJeIrnHnKtAR0yCb8dXuAYXWvqIGfN0EfGZyYxQ?alt=media&token=74805347-642b-4400-94cc-ca6704c20d29, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/laserdimander.appspot.com/o/nICxqQNC60RTGUzErxHSlRnthsyWVSwEUQ1IdDXOJ6chIghFcb?alt=media&token=8746193e-711f-4d44-b900-53cf375d33ca]**